# $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] with localhost or 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, curl

My php script is installed on different hosts

for example

```
http://192.6.6.2/
```

or

```
https://192.168.2.2:50505/
```

or

```
http://example.net:22222/
```

or

```
http://example.net:22222/any_folder
```

what is generic way if I want to curl my "file-2.php" from "file-1.php" using localhost url or ip 127.0.0.1 url

for example in above cases

```
curl http://localhost/
```

or

```
curl https://localhost:50505/
```

or

```
curl http://localhost:22222/
```

or

```
curl http://localhost:22222/any_folder
```

In short I want `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` but with local IP or localhost.

Comment: Generic way would be, if you create virtual host for all the projects you're/you'll work on. Add those ServerName in your hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']
```

for the port

and

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

for the uri